# Regex for removing \n and white space between tags

Tags: jquery, html, regex-negation

How to remove the `\n` and white space between tags?

```
"\n        <td class=\"content\">\n            <div class=\"name\">\n            </div>\n        </td>\n    "
```

I have tried it with `/(\\n)*[\s]/gm` but no progress.

Comment: i have tried with **/(\\n)*[\s]/gm** but no progress

Comment: Please use the "edit" link below your question and put whatever supplemental information you have to your question text; do not use comments for this.

Comment: @veritas:thamks,but i have tried that.its not working!